# Finding nearest value in a list

Tags: r

I have a list of percentiles and I wish to query a nearest value from it by specifying a probability and vice versa. Consider the following code:

```
samples <- runif(1000, 0, 1)
percentiles <- quantile(samples,probs=(0:100)/100)
plot(percentiles)
```

I can easily read the plot(e.g. 50% prob -> 0.5 in this example), however how can I find the nearest value in the list (either by specifying the probability or the value on the Y-axis) ?

Thanks!

Comment: You have a `?vector` of percentiles, not a `?list`

Comment: @RobertKrzyzanowski, true.  But kind of important to know the difference when working in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building off Robert's answer, you can look at all the neighbors with this.  Coincidentally, the result is in `list` form.

```
> zzz <- sapply(1:(length(percentiles)-1), function(i){
    c(sort(percentiles)[i-1], sort(percentiles)[i+1])
    }, USE.NAMES = TRUE)[-1]
```

The use of `USE.NAMES` allows you to access the neighbors easily via the list index.

```
> zzz[99]  ## neighbors of the 99th percentile
##       98%      100% 
## 0.9861953 0.9986512 
> zzz[25]  ## neighbors of the 25th percentile
##       24%       26% 
## 0.2654937 0.2926444 
> zzz[36]  ## neighbors of the 36th percentile
##       35%       37% 
## 0.3756176 0.3864981
```

Answer (score 2):

Sort first and look at the neighbors.

```
i <- 50
sorted_percentiles <- sort(percentiles) 
# the values adjacent to the 50th data point are:
sorted_percentiles[i - 1]
sorted_percentiles[i + 1]
```